# Data to Global String in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

First I want to say sorry for my bad english. It is not my primary language.

Anyway. I am currently working on a project were you have your own profile and stuff. I am already done with my login form and it is working fine, and when I log in it sets my user id from the database as a session named UserID to indicate that I am logged in.

Now, what I wanna ask is, what is the best way to get all my user information from my database in to global strings. So if I for example wanna write the firstname of the logged in user, I can simply do something like this:

```
Response.Write(UserFirstname);
```

Any suggestions? Or is there any smarter way to do this?

Thanks in advance, Jens Kvist

Comment: Are you using some pre-existing authentication libraries, or did you roll your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use encapsulation and a custom object. Read your database into a custom object and then use the individual properties of that object in your example.

[Encapsulation Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson19)

There are a lot of ways to do this. Using encapsulation correctly will make sure that, whatever route you take, you do it in a way that won't make you regret it later.

Also, it looks like you're using ASP.Net Web Forms (judging by 'Response.Write'). That's completely valid but you may want to looking into ASP.Net MVC ([here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials)). Razor can make your life much easier. Make sure it is applicable to your situation, of course.

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

CustomObject newObject = new CustomObject();

newObject.PropertyOne = DatabaseString;
newObject.PropertyTwo = DatabaseString;
```

Then Later:

```
Response.Write(newObject.PropertyOne);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at encapsulation right now! Yea, I am using Web Forms atm. and I agree with you, I will soon jump over to MVC. I have worked a little bit with Razor before.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that retrieves/saves the data from session variables. Or use the identity classes in .net

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it out. Sorry I cannot upvote I am pretty new here.

Comment: Don't need to upvote, just check the best answer or write your final conclusions.  Take care